# How to change drive's name?

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i give other drives and partitions short, meaningful names (in nautilus)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus)

I've got two Windows drives next to the Ubuntu drive, they are called `XXXGB Filesystem`, where XXX is a size (80 and 329). How can I change their names to `Windows` and `Data`. I don't care, they are called strangely in `/media` folder, although it would be nice to know where can I change it too and how may I disable to show a `system drive`, that shouldn't be visible at all.

**How it is now:**

[image]

**How it should look like:**

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Command Line:

- To change the labels of drives use one of these commands:

  ```
  sudo e2label /dev/sdc6 Data
  ```

  OR

  ```
  sudo sudo tune2fs -L Data /dev/sdc6
  ```

  Replace `/dev/sdc6` with the specific drive you want to label and `Data` with the desired label.

  Use `sudo fdisk -l` to find drive names.

  [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131)

### GUI:

- If you prefer GUI option than you can use `Gparted`.

  To install Gparted hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```

  Once installed hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gparted` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or search for `gparted` in Unity Dash and run it from there.

  Make sure the drive you want to label is unmounted, if it's mounted you can unmount it in Gparted, right click on the drive and select unmount.

  To label a drive right click on the drive you want to label and select `Label`, enter the desired label.

  [image]

  Click on the apply button in toolbar. That's it!

  [image]

### How to hide "SYSTEM" partition in Nautilus:

1. Create a file: `99-hide-some-disks.rules`
2. Insert the following line to the file: `KERNEL=="device name", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1",`

   Where device name is `sdaX` or `hdX`
3. Copy the file to `/etc/udev/rules.d`
4. Reboot computer, now the drive from a file is invisible (you can still mount it by hand only).

   Source: Thanks to [Benjamin](https://askubuntu.com/users/53476/benjamin)

Comment: Unfortunately, I suppose, changing partition name is the only option, it must be enough :)
Could you add this to the answer, to be complete, cause I found out, how to hide "SYSTEM" partition in Nautilus:


1. Create a file: 99-hide-some-disks.rules


2. Insert the following line to the file:
KERNEL=="device name", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1",
where device name is sdaX or hdX

3. Copy the file to /etc/udev/rules.d

4. Reboot computer, now the drive from a file is invisible (you can still mount it by hand only)

Thank you.

Comment: You can use "Disk Utility" came by default with your Ubuntu installation.(I have used it on Fedora though. So not sure bout the outcome of it.)

Comment: `alt+f2 and find gparted` not work for me, instead I use `sudo gparted` from console.

Comment: Note: if you don't unmount the disk first, `e2label` will not change the label (and won't even report an error, which is confusing).

Comment: @SridharSarnobat `e2label` worked flawlessly. I renamed label with mounted drive.

Comment: Both solutions fail for my exfat partition. Gparted does not support it apparently and e2label also complaints (Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open ...
... contains a exfat file system labelled ...) Any solution for exfat formatting?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the volume label for them in Windows, they should show up with those names in Ubuntu as well. It works for me at least. I have a Win XP partition, and a shared partition for music/movies/etc… both which show up with their assigned volume labels in both Ubuntu and Windows.

So just boot into Windows, right-click on the drives, and set their labels.

Comment: From what I've found out, I have to edit /etc/fstab to change the name of the files in /media/ directory (by editing file or by using pysdm gui application). So it may be a solution of an additional part, but changing partitions name in Windows isn't an option for me so far.
And disabling SYSTEM partition from mounting isn't solved yet, so please, if you know any other solution, let me know.