# How to change mounted HDD UUID to human-readable?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, uuid

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed on SSD, and I mounted HDD also for data. But when I did this, the UUID it has consists of random set of numbers and letter like this /mnt/9d79a504-bf86-4a1f-99e4-927b9e20df6e and even if I labeled it and gave a simple name to my disk - Storage, I still can't navigate to it like cd /mnt/Storage in terminal, I tried to give it an alias also, but it's failed. So is anyone who can help me with that? 
Thanks!

I checked this links below, which looked similar, but, I forced to ask this question.
[How can I give other drives and partitions short, meaningful names in nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus)
[How to change drive's name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153129/how-to-change-drives-name)

[image: terminal screen]

***UPDATED:***

[image: solved screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what You're looking for is changing the mount point. I believe You can modify `/etc/fstab` manually to change that - just follow the example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Examples - or use build in disks management tool. Search for "disks" in the shell, then find a partition You need, select it, click use 'gears' icon and "Modify mounting options..." (I believe). Disable defaults and change "Mounting point" path. Reboot may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it and then saw your answer! You rock! Your advice was almost identical what I did. I just set a Label for my disk using "GParted", then went to "Disks" and "Edit Mount Options..." and then all what was needed is to change the option "Identify As" from "UUID=..." to "LABEL=...". That's it.

Comment: I believe it's rather Your solution than mine, so it would be totally ok for me if You post it separately and accept as the answer. :) Anyway I'm glad You managed to solve this issue and that I could help in any way, if I did. Thanks to the One I say. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the tools Disks or gparted to do this if the partition is mounted. If you can unmount the partition, edit the label then.  If it's your system partition, you'll have to use a live USB session to do it.

Comment: I solved the problem by using exactly "Disks" and "GParted". Anyway, thank you.