# How to change drive label and default mounting location for exfat drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, exfat

I want to change the label and default mounting location for an external hard drive.

To change the label I have tried both solutions proposed in https://askubuntu.com/a/153183/800252 but they do not work for exfat drives. I already ran sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils before. gparted explicitly does not support exfat and e2label apparently doesn't either. Since it gives an error

```
Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/...
/dev/... contains a exfat file system labelled BadDefaultLabel
```

Similarly I changed the default Mount Point using gparted but it seems it is not being used and it still gets mounted to the default `/media/user/BadDefaultLabel`.

System: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change the drive label in Windows instead. This solved the labeling issue and also my biggest problem with the default mounting point since my annoyance was a space in the file path due to the space in the label.

An ubuntu native solution would have been nicer but the problem is solved.

Comment: Since you have `exfat-utils` installed, the native solution isn't far, take a look [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/exfatlabel.8.html).