# How to create a GRUB2 entry for a "LiveSD" Card

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, sd-card

I want to be able to boot any OS (this case: a Live version of Kubuntu) installed on a SD card (not USB).

I have followed the instructions given [for a USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive). However that won't work properly, the `40_custom` GRUB2 entry that I have now is:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 exec tail -n +3 $0
 # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
 # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
 # the 'exec tail' line above.

  menuentry "PLEASE BOOT ME I AM THE SD CARD" {
       set root=(hd0,1)
       linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1 ro quiet splash
       initrd /initrd.img
 }
```

The option appears on the GRUB menu but whenever I selected it prompts the regular kubuntu splash screen and won't boot from my SD Card (or the HDD, either).

Comment: Does plugging the SD card into a USB adapter work?

Comment: @Tim Thank you for participate in this thread, It does work from the BIOS (with the USB adapter) but again, from the GRUB it won't work. The thing is that I need that USB port while I am on the "Live SD card" and the BIOS doesn't provide SD Card support.

Comment: Boot from a LiveDVD, insert&mount the SD card. and provide below as what device it does come up... Definitely not `hd0`... (mine comes up as `sdc`, but my BIOS allows booting from SD cards)

Comment: @Fabby Mine shows as sdb, how does that change my code? according to the instructions on adding custom entries (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus) my code seems to be all right.

Comment: Never got an acceptance...  But I did get an upvote...  Som tinh wong wit my code?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As your USB stick comes up as sdb, the code should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
 exec tail -n +3 $0
 # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
 # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
 # the 'exec tail' line above.
  menuentry "PLEASE BOOT ME I AM THE SD CARD" {
       set root=(sdb,1)
       linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1 ro quiet splash
       initrd /initrd.img
 }
```

if the OS is installed in the first partition of the USB stick.  ;-)

Comment: You probably going (facepalm) now!  Don't thank me!  ;-) Just click the little grey check-mark under the "0" now.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, turning it into beautiful green and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask