# Ubuntu 15.04 desktop - How can I make Ubuntu boot to the command line?

Tags: server

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 in Virtual Box with the standard GUI.  However, I want to be able to have the option to boot it to the command line and run it without the GUI.  How do I do this?  Have searched Google but can't find a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "text" flag to a grub boot option.

See the steps here to add a new boot option:

[How to add a GRUB2 menu entry for booting installed Ubuntu on a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive)

When you add the code:

```
menuentry "Install on sdb1" {
    set root=(hd1,1)
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1 ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
}
```

Make sure to add text after the word "splash":

```
menuentry "Install on sdb1" {
    set root=(hd1,1)
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1 ro quiet splash text
    initrd /initrd.img
}
```

To change the default boot option to boot in text mode run this command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And then add "text" (without quotes) to the end of the line next to splash.  It should look something like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Will that tutorial work for Ubuntu as well?  Guy is complaining about how different Mint is from other distros in the first few sentences.

Comment: @timbram yeah, I just realized there was a better way

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Let me try this out right now and see how it goes!

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to get it to work.  Even adding those items and it still boots to GUI by default.

Comment: @timbram do you want it to boot to text by default?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @timbram Ok I changed my answer to include that also.