# grub entry for slackware from another drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on my machine with following partition structure:

```
/boot 512MB
/     50G
swap  4G
/home 100G~
```

and I have another drive which has slackware 14.1 on it with following structure:

```
/boot 512M (with working initrd)
(encrypted lvm containing /, swap and home )
```

I want to know if there is a way i can add my slackware system to ubuntu's grub, so that i will be able to boot both operating systems (multi-bootish way).

I tried adding something like following to /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "Slackware" { 
      linux /dev/sdb2/vmlinux 
      initrd /dev/sdb2/initrd.gz
}
```

and to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DISALBE_OS_PROBE=true
```

but when i run `grub-update` it gets cleared.

I have some knowledge of LILO but grub is quite new for me so any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

-**Update:** Thanks oldfred, got it working by doing following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup
sudo modprobe dm-crypt
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 my-crypt
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

going to try the menuentry thing also though.

Comment: I think os-prober should be enabled in /etc/default/grub. And changes made to /boot/grub/boot.cfg are vanished with update-grub, so if you want to add menu entries you'll have to do it in /etc/grub.d/40_custom. And I don't know if the /dev/sdb1/vmlinux syntax will work with GRUB, it's better to use GRUB's syntax (hdX,Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lilo is a Windows type boot loader. So may be easier to chain load to the MBR or PBR of your other drive.

This is a partition boot entry. But note that drive you boot from is always hd0 in grub, but drive order can otherwise vary.

[How to add a GRUB2 menu entry for booting installed Ubuntu on a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359)

```
menuentry "Install on sda (When from sdc) Chainboot" {
set root=(hd1)
chainloader +1
}

menuentry "Install on sdb (from sdc) Chainboot" {
set root=(hd2)
chainloader +1
}

menuentry "Chainload Other Systems Grub Menu on sdc1" {
set root=(hd2,1)
chainloader +1
}


menuentry " " {
set root= 
}

menuentry "System restart" {
echo "System rebooting..."
    insmod reboot
reboot
}    

menuentry "System shutdown" {
echo "System shutting down..."
    insmod halt
halt
}
```

Correct entry to turn off os-prober

Turn off prober

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add this line

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

update grub menu after any change

```
sudo update-grub
```

If using LVM you make be able to get os-prober to work if you add the lvm drivers in Ubuntu and manually mount the encrypted partition (so it is unencrypted) when os-prober runs.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup
```

If other steps to mount & unencrypt needed they are here, just you do not need all the resize instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions