# How to get out of the grub menu in ubuntu?

Tags: grub2

let's say you have multiple versions of ubuntu installed. and you end up accidentally pressing the key ''ESC'' when on the switching screen. it will bring you to the grub menu, right? so how to go back to that switching screen and out of the grub menu?

Comment: What switching screen? Are you referring to the UEFI boot menu that is before grub? Grub should offer to boot all installs if installed in same boot mode. But grub menu has entry to go into UEFI settings (not boot menu). I add to 40_custom my own reboot entry. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/728351/grub-entry-for-slackware-from-another-drive

Comment: maybe i'm wrong about the switching screen's name. maybe it's not called grub. i really don't know. but I'm talking about the black screen that allows you to switch between multiple operating systems when you turn on your computer..

Comment: let's say you have ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 22.04 on your computer. i'm talking about the switching screen that prompts you to chose between them.

Comment: You first get an UEFI boot menu. Often f12 but varies by vendor. You have to check your manual for UEFI system settings key & UEFI boot menu key. And then if using grub, you get grub menu. Why do you want to go back?

Comment: no, i'm talking about when you switch on your computer, and then see a screen with multiple options of operating systems, without pressing any F keys!

Comment: Then there is nothing to go back to, you just choose Ubuntu in grub menu to boot. Default is 10 sec, so it should auto boot after 10 sec unless you changed settings in grub. There are also grub menu items for older kernel in case new one has issues and UEFI system settings.

Comment: when i press ESC it brings me to another screen with a terminal and there's ''grub'' next to the arrow that asks you to type your command

Comment: how do i get out of that terminal and back to the menu screen is what I'm asking. do you understand?

Comment: You get grub>, That is grub command shell. It would have been good to know that first. That is from a mis-configured grub. Sometimes typing exit works. If you know partition your install is in. Does this how partitions? `ls` and then `ls (hdX,Y)/`, the X is your drive and Y is partition, you want to find install, like (hd0,2). then `configfile (hdX,Y)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` where X & Y are drive, partition of your install. If not run Boot-Repair.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: what? i am not a tech person.

Comment: Then use Ubuntu live installer that you used to install it in live mode and download Boot-Repair per instructions in link & post a link to the pastebin site it will give you when you run the report. While most of the time the suggested repair works, best to have report reviewed to make sure those suggested repairs are best.