# GRUB menu in 22.04.2 - os-prober?

Tags: grub2, os-prober

I have 3 disk:

```
/dev/sda - empty
/dev/sdb - Ubuntu 20.04.5
/dev/sdc - Ubuntu 20.04.5
```

I use UEFI bootloader to boot any system.

I decided to install in `/dev/sda` Ubuntu 22.04.2.

After installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 I was surprise when `/dev/sda` showed me GRUB menu with `/dev/sdb - Ubuntu 20.04.5`, `/dev/sdc - Ubuntu 20.04.5`.

I want to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 without GRUB menu like `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`. Also, I know `os-prober` should be disabled by default in 22.04.

I know I can edit `/etc/default/grub` and hide the GRUB menu or I can disable other SATA in UEFI but it doesn't answer at the questions why do this case is? What services do other OSs detect? Is this a bug? Can I get clear install without the GRUB menu?

...or I have to go around with home made methods like editing `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: You appear to be wanting what was fixed in this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1955109) reversed?   Almost all users wanted what you got, and not what you're after; but it's only a simple configurable change (the grub 2.06 change was reported first [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html))   FYI:  the same behavior reported in my provided bug report occurred in other OSes as it was a change to what prior products/releases have done, thus it was reported on other OSes & corrected there too

Comment: @guiverc I don't understand people saying `prober-os` is unsafe, but we want to use it. This is funny. :) Now probobly there will be who want other case. In generally, need regard to do both cases and to create parameter to control that. I see it all. But how I can achieve my goal? Only home made cases?

Comment: I prefer to turn off os-prober. And then add whatever I want to boot into 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive
insmod reboot example:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/728351/grub-entry-for-slackware-from-another-drive

Comment: Comment #5 in the bug report told readers how to get the older-behavior from grub 2.06; you want what the bug report was about so do the opposite ie. `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` (reverse of =false is =true) but otherwise the instructions in that comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)