# Missing partition from boot list

Tags: boot

I have various ubuntu versions on different partitions

- 14.04 on dev/sda1
- 16.04 on dev/sda6
- and so on.

They all used to appear  in the boot list when starting the computer, but suddenly one dev/sda* is no more in the list and so I have no way to work with this particular machine. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you  run `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks for lending me your glasses.......

Comment: The issue with multiple installs is that one controls booting but will not have updated entry to second/third/etc install until you update it and go back to first and run updates. You can boot a link file to newest kernel and avoid a lot of the sequence of updating grub issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own grub entry if you know where the kernel, etc is. Basically edit /etc/grub.d/40_custom by copying another section and specify the different kernel/file locations, then run 'update-grub2', using this link for reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked with just updating grub. The link suggested is also quite useful.

Comment: You are very welcome!