# dual boot UEFI problem cannot open the other os

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-7

My laptop is HP 655.

I had Windows 7 installed in UEFI mode, then I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on another partition.

There was no option for Ubuntu in the boot manager, only Windows 7.

Then I used the BIOS recovery tool and now Ubuntu is the only one showing and I can't boot Windows 7.

How can I show the two boot options?

Comment: Did you install Windows in EFI mode and Ubuntu in BIOS mode?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue. My interim fix was to use rEFInd which worked really well. I use it on USB. If it picks up both OS, you can install it as your boot manager.

Comment: how to use it ?

Comment: Download the rEFIt iso from http://refit.sourceforge.net/ and install it onto a bootable USB. Set your Bios to boot from USB and it should load, showing your two OS.

Comment: Agreed mate. Sorry, I overlooked that. And I think the rEFIt website points you to the new one.

Comment: @Jexodus you can edit your answer.

Comment: Done mate. Sorry, should have done that sooner...

Answer (score 0):

For GRUB to be able to detect multiple OS's on a drive, you need to install the os-prober package alongside GRUB.

The steps for this would be:

1. Install Windows to your drive first
2. Install Ubuntu secondly
3. Boot into your new Ubuntu system.
4. Open up a new terminal session
5. Run `sude update-grub`

If everything goes well GRUB should detect your Windows system and add it to the list of OS's to pick when you reboot your system. For more info refer to the official [Ubuntu page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup) and [this thread on GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine)

Comment: GRUB normally detects automatically.