# Dual boot problem after installing a new SSD-2TB disk

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

My configuration - dual boot system

- SSD-1TB (Ubuntu 16.04)
- SSD-250G (Ubuntu 16.04)

Because of insufficient space I replaced the SSD-1TB disk with a new SSD-2TB disk.  I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it from USB stick with the SSD-250G disk disconnected before installation.

After the installation completed I reconnected the SSD-250G disk, but I can't boot from it, it's always booting from the new SSD-2TB disk. Finally, unless I disconnected the cable of the new SSD-2TB disk.

Then I ran boot-repair and [this is my boot summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FZPxDB2Hns/).

Comment: Are you dual booting two instance of Ubuntu or is there a Windows install somewhere? If it’s just Ubuntu x 2 connect both drives and boot the one that works. Then update grub. There is sure to be a guide to do that on here if you do a search

Comment: Only 2 Ubuntu. No Windows system.
Previsou it worked without problem

Comment: I think that by disconnecting the 250G drive when you installed to the 2T drive you didn’t give the new installation the opportunity to set up grub for the 250G drive. You should be able to do that from the new install by updating grub. To do this type sudo update-grub in a terminal

Comment: Followed 3 on
https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine

sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1001470 488396799 487395330 232.4G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1001472 488396799 487395328 232.4G 8e Linux LVM

add follow to /etc/grub.d/40_custom
menuentry "Install on sdb" {
    set root=(sdb)
    linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb ro quiet splash
    initrd /initrd.img
}

Edit grub to turn off os-prober

Still failed only booting SSD-2TB

Comment: Did it again;

Cancel all entries on;
/etc/default/grub

/etc/grub.d/40_custom

sudo cp -a /boot/grub/grub.cfg.backup /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sudo update-grub

Still only booting SSD-2TB disk

Comment: booting SSD-250G disk

On the boot-loader page following line popup on top;
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22

Does it matter ?

Comment: It’s hard to follow exactly what you have done when you provide complex updates as comments. It’s better to append to the original question. If I were you I would now wipe the 2T drive and start again. This time have both drives connected. I’ve never tried installing two identical versions of Ubuntu on the same machine and I’m wondering why you disconnected the 250G drive while doing it. Do you hit an issue with the installer if the 250G drive is connected? You will probably need to go the “something else” route at the partitioning step. The pastebin info suggests this legacy not UEFI correct?