# Instaling a second linux system on MBR drive

Tags: dual-boot, mbr

Here is what gparted show:

dev/sda a

dev/sda1 linux_swap

dev/sda2 linux #1 (alt linux)

dev/sda3 linux#1 home dir

dev/sda4 free space

How should I install linux 2 (ubuntu) so that I could use dual boot?

I tried installing ubuntu to sda4 and set installer to write bootloader to sda4, but this way only linux #1 is detectable. I don't get offered to select what OS I want to start.

Thank you!

PS I was kindly pointed out that mint is offtopic here.  I changed it to ubuntu.What my actions should be in this case?

Comment: Installing Mint is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here, I am sorry.

Comment: Ah I see... I don't quite get it coz it's still ubuntu.. but OK

What about installing ubuntu then instead of mint?

Comment: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu but many things are different. Advice that works for Ubuntu may or may not work. It is best to ask at the Linux Mint forum.

Comment: If you don't want Ubuntu, but a flavor (different desktop) of Ubuntu, they can be downloaded at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  (*they don't include other non-Ubuntu distros like Mint, but all official flavors are on-topic here and other Ubuntu sites*)

Comment: Kubuntu looks OK. I guess I'll give it a try.

So, if I'm installing kubuntu, how should I proceed?  
Regards

Comment: If you install grub to partition, you have to boot into first install and run `sudo update-grub` and do that everytime second install gets new kernel or major updates. Or if you install grub to MBR with second install it will add first automatically but on update still have to update grub. You can make it easier as Ubuntu uses links to newest kernel which you can boot. Or you can use a configfile to boot into other grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614

Comment: Seems like your main problem was installing bootloader on sda4.  Usually it is installed to sda(no numbers).