# Ubuntu Studio 22.10 dual boot with Window 10 grub-customizer

Tags: dual-boot

Installed Ubuntu Studio 22.10 dual boot with Windows 10. Want to use grub-customizer but can't get it from ppa danielricher because there is no release file. Don't want to use terminal commands (newbie!!). So, what is the solution please?

Comment: Manually editing grub is not all that difficult. How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614

Comment: Either get used to the terminal or switch to 22.04 for which the ppa has a release file. Or live with grub as it is without customizing. The choice is always yours.