Dual booting two versions of Ubuntu
I have a version of Ubuntu 22.04 installed on /dev/sda. I installed a new copy of 22.04 on /dev/sdc hoping that the system would dual-boot but it only recognizes the new installation. When making the new installation I specified that the boot device was /dev/sda. Should I re-install and if so how? Otherwise, what should I do to dual boot?

Default install uses first drive's ESP for booting. If you want two installs totally separate you need an ESP - efi system partition on sdc, which you probably do not have. Be sure to use gpt partitioning.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Newer version of Ubuntu use Subiquity installer that works to choose second or external drive. Also Lubuntu and 24.04 Kubuntu use Calamares installer which works. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

I want both systems to show up in the boot menu and be bootable.

Even with one ESP, you should be able to boot both systems from grub menu. But will only have one "ubuntu" entry in UEFI. If you want two "ubuntu" entries in UEFI, then you have to have two ESP partitions. I change description from "ubuntu" to version, so I can tell them apart. But only one entry per ESP will work. If grub not show both entries, run this: sudo update-grub. And after updates you may need to run it again in other install or https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine/848614#848614 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

I have 2 instances of 22.04.5 booting from a UEFI drive. One I copied from a legacy boot drive with gparted. The other I installed an ISO from a USB flash drive. Had to do it twice for some reason. Once 22.04.5 was installed from the USB flash drive both instances of 22.04.5 showed up in the GRUB menu along with a copy of 24.04.1.
