# How to add a menu entry for testing kernel in GRUB2?

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I installed Ubuntu on a USB drive and my partition table is

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15514730496 bytes, 30302208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb643db4f

 Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id     Type
/dev/sdb1  *        2048 20537343 20535296  9.8G  83     Linux
/dev/sdb2       20539390 30300159  9760770  4.7G   5     Extended
/dev/sdb5       20539392 30300159  9760768  4.7G  82     Linux swap / Solaris
```

I created my kernel following by this link http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernel-101-lets-write-a-kernel

when I add menuentry in etc/default/grub (grub.cfg)

```
menuentry 'mykernel' {
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    multiboot /boot/mykernel-01 ro
}
```

and when run command

```
update-grub
```

this gives error

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: menuentry: not found
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Does Ubuntu use `grub-mkconfig` command, what system is this?

Comment: I have windows10 on my ssd and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my 16 gb usb.

Comment: please change ure tag to `16.04`

Comment: I changed it, any solution for this error.

Comment: please look at this [article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive)

Comment: I tried but this is not working.

Comment: I don't see quote marks around the root value. please do `set root=(hd1,msdos1)`

Comment: Let me rephrase that `set root='hd1,msdos1'`

Comment: I tried with all formats but not working.