# sudo update-grub is not affecting the grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, os-prober

I have multiple OS's installed on my laptop, and am running grub from Ubuntu to boot them. If I run `sudo update grub` it finds all the systems, as you can see in the image.

[image: 1]

The problem is that after I reboot the system, it remains the same as it was when I originally installed Grub.

Here is the grub.cfg file:

[image: part 1]

[image: part 2]

To rephrase the problem, I am getting all the options listed in the grub.cfg file, but it only includes the OS's I had when I originally installed Ubuntu with grub on it. Whenever I run `sudo update-grub`, it shows that it detected new systems, but does not write them to grub.cfg. At least that's what I think is happening.

If I should include any other files, or information, please let me know.

Comment: When you turn on your laptop which OS appear on grub menu ?

Comment: In Terminal run `grep  menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and post up output.

Comment: It looks like it is looping, or finding same partitions over & over. So then is update to grub not written?

Comment: @PaulBenson I added the grub.cfg to the post.

Comment: @kannzzmm2 All the menu entries in the grub.cfg file appear there, but I can not get it to update.

Comment: @oldfred I am not sure why it is looping, and if that is part of the problem, but it is most certainly detecting them. The problem is that (I think) it does not write the updates to the grub.cfg file.

Comment: Does the system where you enter `update-grub` actually own the MBR?   You need to run that command on the owner of the MBR (only one OS can own the first sector of your media), OR make the OS you want to own it - take ownership & then run `update-grub`.   The first stage of grub is the MBR and if it's pointing to another `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file ; re-creating that grub.cfg file should do nothing.

Comment: Since all the menu entries are shown in your grub file then what exactly isn't being updated? Are you trying to add or remove some of them? Do these menu entries boot you up into the respective systems?

Comment: Your list may be so long you have to scroll down in the grub menu to see all the entries. With multiple installs, I typically turn os-prober off and only add entries I want to 40_custom. And often simple configfile entry to boot into other install's grub menu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same symptoms.

Turned out that the Ubuntu 20.04 installer had incorrectly mounted the Windows 10 EFI partition in `/etc/fstab` at `/boot/efi` for the Ubuntu installation.

This meant that new kernels and other grub updates were being added to the wrong grub.cfg in the wrong partition.

I just mounted the correct Ubuntu EFI partition in `/etc/fstab` and updated grub and bingo, my grub menu was properly updated.

Not sure if this is a bug in the Ubuntu dual boot installer for EFI or just my system.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` within terminal and check output.