# Error entering to my ubuntu 20.04 because it is full and grub doesn't recognize my Usb

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, usb, resize

I am trying to enter my ubuntu-desktop 20.04 but it doesn't allow me because it is full.

[image]

```
/dev/nvme0n1p8:clean, 430719/3612672 files, 13722097/14444032 blocks
```

I wanted to resize the Ubuntu partition with a USB live containing the Ubuntu ISO image and using Gparted but the grub doesn't recognize my USB.

[image]

In this image, you can see that the grub only recognizes my Ubuntu partition, Advanced options, Windows Boot manager, and UEFI settings but it doesn't show me my USB which is connected to my computer.

Can anyone help me?

My laptop specs are the following:

BIOS 1.1.3, Nvidia Gtx 1050 4 GB, Intel corei7-7700HQ, and 16 GB RAM

Comment: You can boot a USB using your internal GRUB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268001/grub-menu-entry-for-booting-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive

Answer (score 1):

> In this image, you can see that the grub only recognizes my ubuntu partition

Grub only knows about boot devices with bootable operating systems that it's been told about. Booting from the USB device is a function of your machine's BIOS. Normally this is done with a key press on boot but it varies between machines. It might be Esc, Del, F2, F8, F10, F12 or something else, so you need to consult your machine's manual about overriding the default boot device.

That said, I would advise against expanding the partition until a) you have a backup of your treasured stuff, and b) you have booted into the USB device and cleaned up some space by deleting files, and c) you have investigated the cause of the partition filling up. A look in `/var/log` is in order because if there is an error then the logs could have been spammed by the kernel to the point that the log filled up your drive.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. I will back up all my files and then expand the partition as you comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Encryption of your home folder?.
If you are using Encryption Ubuntu needs some free space in order to being able to decrypt.
So you can boot with a Ubuntu Live or a rescue distro, mount the drive, make some space, for example deleting logs under /var/log and then unmount and restarting should be fine.