# Installation of Ubuntu 22.10 on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb-installation, 22.10

I want to install Ubuntu 22.10 on my computer. I went through this tutorial https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview, but I ended at step 4. Boot from USB flash drive.

My computer already has a dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu 16.04. I got stuck at this boot menu.

[image: GNU Grub menu]

Neither option leads to the OS installation menu. How can I proceed with installation?

Comment: On my HP laptop pushing F9 on boot will let me choose the drive to boot, even Live USB drives. –

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your bios isn’t set to read the usb as a higher priority than grub on the hard drive / ssd. Grub won’t offer you boot from usb - it just lets you select from any of the installed OS’s.

You need to enter your computer’s bios settings and set usb to the first option.

Enter bios with the relevant key (it probably flashes briefly at the bottom of the screen after turning on); or check your hardware’s literature / search online. If you can’t find out which key to  press, try <kbd>Esc</kbd> / <kbd>f2</kbd> / <kbd>f10</kbd> /  <kbd>f12</kbd> / <kbd>Del</kbd> in turn (holding each one down in turn during the power on process usually does the trick). Once there, how you tell the system what boot order to use depends on the hardware, but it’s usually quite intuitive.

Once you’ve done that, reboot and it should go to the usb and let you install.

Comment: I tried to run BIOS, but it froze and won't open. Is there please any other possibility of how to try your approach?

Comment: UEFI/BIOS should not freeze? What brand/model system? Where exactly does it freeze? Is this after a full "cold" boot or full shutdown, not "warm" reboot.

Comment: @Humphrey Appleby - unfortunately no, I don’t think there’s anything you can do if you can’t get into / modify settings in bios. At what point did it freeze?

Comment: @oldfred When I hit F10 it returns a black screen with the string "F10... BIOS Setup Options" in left bottom corner, see picture ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/qf7gz.jpg. And nothing else happens. The type of laptop is HP 250 G5.

Comment: @Humphrey Appleby - (1) try turning off completely (including ensuring fast start up in windows disabled), wait about a minute then try again; (2) if you really struggle to get into bios this way, you might find you can change boot order from within Windows (depending on version) - have a look here https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/change-the-boot-order-on-windows/

Comment: Have you updated UEFI/BIOS from HP to latest version? Perhaps similar: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467077

Comment: Your existing grub menu item "System setup" should take you to the BIOS/UEFI settings.

Comment: I have tried the solution suggested by @Will (solution (2)), and I selected option "Run from USB" (resp. something like that) after that I selected option "ubuntu," and since then my computer freezes totally at the black screen from the picture above.

Comment: @Will: To boot a Live USB from the computers GRUB see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1268111/43926