# boot-repair claims to fix grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

**This is the output of boot-repair:**

---

Bootsektor wurde erfolgreich repariert.

Bitte auf ein Papier die folgende Adresse notieren:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h58hKSrJ9y/

Falls Sie ein Startproblem haben, geben Sie hier diese Adresse an:
boot.repair@gmail.com oder in Ihrem bevorzugten Hilfeforum.

Sie können Ihren Rechner nun neu starten.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 21.04 entry (nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !

---

Assumptions:

- I installed new Ubuntu 21.04. on `/dev/nvme1`
- grub2 is installed on `/dev/nvme0`

Expected: Old Ubuntu 20.04. is bootable from `dev/nvme0`

Actual: Only new installation of Ubuntu 21.04. boots in grub2

This is my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

---

```
menuentry "ubuntu 20.04" {
     insmod part_gpt
     insmod chain
     set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
     chainloader /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
}
```

---

How to add Ubuntu 20.04. to grub menu?

Comment: Is old install encrypted & new install not encrypted? You need drivers. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup` Then run `sudo update-grub`. Your drive as seen from grub may be hd1, not hd0. I prefer labels now: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

Comment: thank you, but the commands do not change my Grub2 behaviour: I will try from USB live filesystem next...

Comment: Can you do the configfile type entry to the other install? On my system boot drive is always hd0. So when booting a grub on drive normally sdb, it is hd0 and all other drives are then in order. Unless I also have a flash drive plugged in and then flash drive is sda on reboot and hdX. Often have to experiment.