# Triple boot Win10 Ubuntu 20.04 and Fedora36

Tags: dual-boot

I have two HDDs. The first one has a dual boot win10 and Ubuntu 20.04. UEFI boot. I want to install Fedora 36 to the second one. How can I ensure that the Ubuntu boot loader will be used and it will recognise Fedora36?

Comment: Install Fedora without the boot loader, then after installed, you boot into Ubuntu you can run `update-grub` and I'd expect it to detect Fedora 36 (*rawhide* or any version as long as it's on a compatible file-system Ubuntu recognizes... ie. instructions will vary on details you didn't provide)

Comment: Ok, but how can I install fedora without a boot loader?

Comment: This is a Ubuntu Q&A support site, not a Fedora one.  SE *Unix & Linux* covers all GNU/Linux, BSD, Unix etc. and thus covers both Ubuntu & Fedora... If it was me, I'd just install Fedora & post-install make whichever OS you want to control the boot take ownership of it...  I'm currently running QA-test install of 20.04.5 on a system with Fedora & OpenSuSE... and it's what I plan to do..  (*details as to if your using uEFI or legacy were also not provided which may influence how its done.. but we don't support Fedora*)

Comment: During installation there should be an option to not install a bootloader, but I don’t use Fedora so not totally sure. If there isn’t an option during installation, feel free to ask on Unix and Linux SE where Fedora is on-topic, though. Side note: having a backup (somewhere other than your main machine) is always a good idea, but even more so when installing a new OS

Comment: fyi:   I should have mentioned a `grub-install` may also be required in my first comment..

Comment: UEFI boot all of them. And the reason why I wrote my question here is that I want to keep Ubuntu. Sorry

Comment: I would install Fedora with its ESP on its drive, so it could boot without Ubuntu. Does Fedora still default to LVM? You can use that, but have to add the LVM drivers to Ubuntu for Ubuntu to see it. Or just use standard partitioning. You then also can configfile into Fedora's UEFI from Ubuntu's grub, so get full grub menu. Or add a boot stanza into 40_custom, but it may need update with every Fedora update. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive