Ubuntu grub os-prober not finding Bazzite install
I've been dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows for quite awhile now and everything has worked perfectly fine. I have Ubuntu and Windows installed on two separate drives.
Recently, I added in another drive and installed Bazzite to it, so that I am now triple-booting. However, when I run sudo update-grub in Ubuntu, the os-prober only finds the Windows install, not the Bazzite install. However, if I go into my UEFI Bios settings and choose to boot from the drive with Bazzite installed, I can see that the Bazzite install boots just fine.
How can I get the Bazzite install to be displayed on the grub menu at boot, so that I can choose to boot into Ubuntu, Windows, or Bazzite? If it's relevant, I believe Bazzite is Fedora-based.
Edit:
I am using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10. Ubuntu is installed on Drive A and is using EXT4. Windows is installed on Drive B and is using NTFS. /boot/efi is on Drive B as well.
I have added Drive C and installed Bazzite on it. It is EXT4.
I am not using any encryption on any drives.

Are either of these links any use? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252936/grub2-boot-to-a-second-another-hard-disk https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335247/two-linux-distributions-grub-does-not-detect-other-one

Is Bazzite installed in UEFI boot mode? Did you use LVM and do not have LVM drivers in Ubuntu? Often then mounting the install (and adding drivers if needed) & then running os-prober will work. Or you can do a configfile to the ESP on second drive by adding entry manually into 40_custom. Some examples: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392441&p=13816046#post13816046 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359

I have edited my question to add additional details.

You need to add an entry for Bazzite OS to Ubuntu's GRUB boot menu.
Update the grub bootloader using the following command:
sudo update-grub 

If that doesn't work install Boot-Repair and run it on Ubuntu using the following commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

The third line in the above code block contains the boot-repair command which is used to start the Boot-Repair GUI.
