how to use / boot the operating system of an internal hard drive from old laptop as an external hard drive through usb port of newer laptop?
I have 2 laptops. The older one is an HP Pavilion g6. The Newer one is an HP Envy. Both laptops have Ubuntu operating systems. I have removed the hard drive from the Pavilion and connected it externally to one of Envy's USB ports with a SATA hard drive adapter. So far, I can access the Pavilion's hard drive and retrieve all files that are stored through terminal.
Here are the leading 2 questions I have.
First, how may I boot directly into the Pavilion hard drive at start up? Yes, with the intention of using only the Pavilion’s operating system. It seems that the Envy is not recognizing the Pavilion in its Boot Menu, which I suppose is normal?
Second, notwithstanding the answer to the first question, is it possible to somehow access the Pavilion hard drive (through the Envy of course) and start up that older version of Firefox ? This would mean I can use the previous settings of Firefox that I have set, including seeing the open tabs, the bookmarks, browsing history, etc, without using the operating system on the Envy. Is this possible? I would imagine that this cannot be done without first booting into Pavilion’s operating system ??

Just to be sure, when you're talking about the "boot menu" you're referring to the UEFI's boot menu right? Not GRUB's boot menu, correct?

i will explain how i get to the "boot menu."  after i turn on the laptop, i repeatedly press the escape button. this takes me to a "start up menu."  on this menu is written the following:
F1    system information
F2    system diagnostics
F9    boot menu
F10  BIOS  setup
F11  system recovery
Enter-  continue starup
that's it.
the word "grub"  is not used.

Got you, then you need to then press F9 and look for the old drive in the list; if the drive isn't listed, you'll have to try and enable legacy support, refer to the answer I posted, although that's mostly a matter of pressing "F10" instead of "F9" at startup and of try and looking for the right option to enable in the BIOS

You would only need legacy support to directly boot old install. You can add a boot stanza to grub on new pc to boot install on old pc. Does not matter if UEFI or BIOS or even if MBR or gpt. Although I have used gpt with old BIOS boot. I booted my UEFI install on external SSD with BIOS grub boot stanza. Example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive Just add a boot stanza to your 40_custom. You also can just copy entire FF profile to new system. I typically copy FF profile to external SSD so versions are same.

I'll wager your newer laptop doesn't allow to boot from non-UEFI / legacy sources by default (which is a common occurrence on newer laptops), or, that it lacks legacy support altoghether (which unfortunately can happen, e.g., on some HP desktops, I'm not sure about their laptops), and that your old system has been installed without UEFI support.
To fix this issue, you'll have to refer to your laptop's manual, which will guide you to in entering the BIOS, in order to change some settings.
The feature you want to enable is often named something like "Legacy support", and is often nested under a group of options often named something like "Boot" / "Boot options", but this will vary from vendor to vendor, so if you're having a hard time finding the right option, try and refer to your laptop's manual again.
After having done that, you should be able to see the old system listed in your boot menu.
About Firefox: assuming both laptops have the snap version of Firefox installed, all you need to do should be replacing the ~/snap/firefox/current/ and ~/snap/firefox/common/ folders on your newer laptop's home directory with the same folders found in your older laptop's home directory.
After that, the instance of Firefox on your newer laptop should mirror the instance of Firefox on your older laptop (unless some drastic change has happened between the version installed on your older laptop and the version installed on your newer laptop that broke compatibility, but honestly this works more often than not).
