Ubuntu not booting from booting option?
Earlier , I installed Ubuntu on my PC and a booting option called "Ubuntu" appeared on the my booting options when pressing F9 (HP notebook)but then I deleted the OS by deleting the partition it was in. Now when picking "ubuntu" boot option nothing appears but a command line.
I installed Ubuntu again but the ubuntu boot option still doesn't work and to run ubuntu I have to enter "hard disk boot".
mM question is, how to start ubuntu from the boot option as I used to before uninstalling it the first time?

If you press f10 and go to harddrive boot optios, do you have Ubuntu there?

Yes , and thats how I used to start Ubuntu OS before,  but as I said before .. when I select it now a command line appears because I deleted its partition before installing the new Ubuntu OS.

Ubuntu entry in UEFI uses GUID/partuuid or ESP - efi system partition to know where to find /EFI/ubuntu folder for boot file. If you redid ESP, it would have new partuuid. And then grub in ESP uses uuid and 3 line grub command to configfile into the full grub.cfg in your install. Also HP does not support the change of boot order from efibootmgr that grub uses to make Ubuntu first entry. You have to change boot order in HP's system settings F9, not boot menu F10.https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive
