/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg without using uuid
I have a small ubuntu system disk.  After initial install of ubuntu, I used dd to clone every byte of my system disk to a second (mirror) disk of the same size.   Every night a script using rsync is run to keep the mirror disk updated. Both disks are permanently mounted in hot-swap bays.
The idea is that if the system disk fails, I only need to swap the mirror disk into the system bay and reboot to have the system running again. Then (at my leisure) re-initialise a new mirror disk in the second bay.
The only trouble is that the initial install created the EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file (copied to the mirror disk) with its first line instructing grub to look for the uuid of the failed system disk.
I need to edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg so that will not use UUIDs.
BTW.  I have uncommented that line in /etc/default/grub which eliminated the use of UUIDs elsewhere but it doesn't seem to to have done what I need.

If you used dd to clone, you also copied UUIDs. That works only if you do not boot with both drives connected after you made clone. Some have had system boot into one drive one time and other drive next time getting them totally out of sync. I prefer new clean install & rsync  of data. Better to just plan to restore from your normal backup after new install. I use rsync, but more knowledgeable users suggest rdiff backup from a server.

Thank you for your response olfred but you offered no response to the question asked.

So we know details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ You can use labels, partlabels, UUID, or partuuid. https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive  But if clone UUIDs will be identical & you need same entry to boot.

1> created a new, empty MBR using fdisk on /dev/sda ( it's a 'small' drive 1TB )
this eliminates the GPT IDs but creates a simpler MBR ID
2> created a new 200MB EFI partitition 1 (type EF )
3> created a new 500GB linux partition 2 (type 83 )
Formatted partition 1 FAT32
Formatted Partition 2 ext4
clean installed Ubuntu server 22.04 LTE
ran "e2label /dev/sda2 ROOT_SYSTEM"
mounted /dev/sda1 in /mnt/sda1
edited /mnt/sda1/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg to have the first line
"search.fs_label ROOT_SYSTEM root hd0,msdos2"
clone the root disk using "dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb"
use "e2label /dev/sdb2 ROOT_MIRROR" to differentiate the root and mirror drives. Use DiskEditor to change the ID number of /dev/sdb
All done, all works except the root system drive has not yet failed.
