Howto start an exsisting Ubuntu installation from USB
I want to start my existing Ubuntu from USB.
There is dual boot with Windows but the systempartition
has been destroyed due to a formatting fail.
At first: If I can start the pc-Ubuntu from USB so I can go back
to the current situation and use my pc further.
The next step will be to restore the systempartition of Windows.
(Suppose the bootmenu is/was there too.)
What I have to do?

I don't understand what you're trying to do, a restore will depend on what backup strategy you have in place, and we'll only know that if you tell us. You don't tell us what Ubuntu product & release you're asking about, so we can't really help there, but you can boot most Ubuntu systems live and explore what exists on your disks from there, even make config & other changes too.

You cannot start the PC Ubuntu from USB. You can boot from a live Ubuntu installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option. Then you can try to fix the internal partition.

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have to have grub installed to flash or external drive. Similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive  I like to have full installs to larger flash drives, but now use SSD as external drives as so much faster.

@user68186. This seems to be a solution. But I'm or was unsure whether I can start an exsist installation from a live system. I've no options. If I can't start the Pc-Ubuntu , I don't get back.

@guiverc
this is not very nice if you publish overall your wisdom and ignore the procedere
spontaneously:
Thunderbird, evolution, snap, a.s.o. removed after fail installation of ssh...

@guiverc
already barred by Stack Exchange.
Remember my name. I don't want your "support" at anytime.
