# Ubuntu renamed and doubled up External HDDs

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I added my external (usb) hard drives to the `/etc/fstab` file. After rebooting, there was an error that kept Ubuntu from booting. I used Maintenance `nano /etc/fstab` and removed those drives. Ubuntu then booted but my externals are now doubled up and renamed. My internal HDDs are also renamed from their label to their UUID.

Here's what I am seeing:

[image]

The renamed externals have all of my files on the renamed drives causing me to have to remap my libraries in Plex.
How can I correct this?

FYI, I followed a youtube video to add those externals to the `/etc/fstab` file so they would mount on boot (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPDhoYNao1o���������������������������������������������), but Ubuntu did not like that for some reason.

Thank you.

Comment: I think instructions are more for internal drives. With external drives, they will get mounted again by udisks. I prefer to label all partitions particularly external drive partitions so they are mounted by label. You can us Disks or gparted to add labels. If newer gpt then there are two labels, one system & one gpt. http://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus

Comment: Thanks for the info. I prefer them named by label too, but Ubuntu was naming them by their UUID. It took a couple of more reboots, but everything seems to be working fine now. Hopefully it will stay that way.
I tried to use gparted, but it just spun and never collected any info.