# Mounted Partitions ....15chars

Tags: command-line, partitioning

I'm new to ubuntu and I have problem with the partitions. I have 3 mounted partitions but I can only go to `OS` by `cd OS` while I can't go to `New Volume`. That is probably because there is a space in its name.

How can I change its name (label) or how can I go to this partition by command line?

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put the name in doble quotes or add backslash before space like `New\ Volume`

Comment: Thank you. I can do it now. But is there any way to change its name?

Comment: Yes, see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/276928/295286   or http://askubuntu.com/a/147327/295286

Comment: I tried it but it says Cannot change label on mounted device of type filesystem:ntfs.
 (udisks-error-quark, 11)

Comment: @NguyenAnhTuan  ok, so unmount the partition, and try again.