# Deleting folders in /media/username/

Tags: kubuntu, fstab, media

I am using kubunu 20.04 from an external usb 3.1 HDD. That means that any time I connect my kubuntu in a new pc/laptop, new folders appear under /media/myusername, depending on the hard drives or media in that computer. Now I am trying to control that with the fstab file, forcing them to mount in a specific folder under /media/myusername instead of the alphanumeric default folder kubuntu creates.
My question is if I can safely delete the folders that had been created by the system, and no longer need, under the /media/myusername folder; without harming the system in any way.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If these folders are empty, and none of the partitions are mounted to these folders, then you can delete them. At worst, they will be created again by the system if there are no corresponding entry in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: Typically it is just offering to mount existing partitions that have data. But they will be mounted by UUID. Better to label all partitions, so then default mount is by label. You can see labels: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` I have used gparted, disks (gnome-disks) and command line to label partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions  or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus