# I think i need a hand with my Gparted partitions, maybe mount-points + automounts?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, fstab, automount, mountpoint

Hello Im looking to a simple way of using my 2 empty partitions i did format with Gparted, They seem unmounted and im not very sure about setting up the mount points and auto-mount, Im just arriving from windows and im not looking back. Anyone can help ? ( for the details they are lone partitions on their disks boot and system swap was made on a third disk.

!{Listimage}(https://pasteboard.co/oUmywe1f8TuK.png)  LSBLK -F yes i woul like to have them permanent @oldfred

Comment: Post this: `lsblk -f`  Are these partitions you want to permanent mount with fstab when you reboot or occasionally mount just by clicking on them with file browser.

Comment: well i dont find the square brackets so you are most likely seing the same as me only the link toward the image i took..i want them permanent mounted , i took the image to have each collum on top of each item properly, a copy paste was too messy

Comment: Welcome, Benoit.  What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I prefer labels, but you can use UUID to keep unique. You can use Disks, gparted or command line to add labels: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus or `sudo e2label /dev/sdXY data` or /dev/nvme0n1p1. You also need ownership & permissions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Linux, Benoit!

Just a reminder, there are no safety nets in linux.

**Always make a backup!**

The following Bash commands will do what you ask.  Be certain the partitions are correct for your environment in the "for vol ..." line.

```
# Become super user - "danger Will Robinson!"
sudo su

# Make backup fstab - in case things go bad
cp /etc/fstab /tmp/fstab.bkup

# Make temporary target fstab
cp /etc/fstab /tmp/fstab.tmp

# Create mount points and fstab entries
# Volume names will vary - use 'lsblk -f' to find yours
for vol in sda1 nvme0n1p1
do
  mkdir -p /mnt/$vol 
  UUID=$(lsblk -fno UUID /dev/$vol) 
  printf "UUID=%s\t/mnt/%s\text4\tdefaults\t0\t2\n" $UUID $vol >> /tmp/fstab.tmp
done
```

Check that /tmp/fstab.tmp looks good.  That is identical to /etc/fstab but with the additional lines added for the new partitions.  If all looks good:

```
cp /tmp/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab
sync;sync
mount -a
exit
```

Comment: Thanks alot !!! :) im sorry i had the window lowered it works great !! very appreciated

Comment: i think i made one slight mistake adding the sync;sync after /ect/fstab on the same line, im not certain but now i seem to have UUID=sync in my Fstab (and thats now that i see your wise warning) hehe im guessing i have to enter the UUID manually in the file is there one UUID for the whole Pc or one per drive