# How i can use D: Drive in Dual Boot From Ubuntu(Single Hard Disk)?

Tags: disk-usage, fdisk

I want to use my 1TB Hard disk in ubuntu. I have dual-booted Windows And Ubuntu. I can't see D in Ubuntu, in `disks` it says unmounted. I'm booting from SSD(C:)

Comment: D is a Windows construct. What is it your are seeing in Disks? Suggest you Google how to mount a hard disk in Ubuntu.

Comment: /dev/sdb4  1323008 1953521663 1952198656 930.9G Microsoft basic data
Thats what i saw. Im using C for dual boot as well. But i want to use both hard disks like Windows. Its not D actually F i remember. Its a streotype of D thats why i mentioned like that

sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /storage -- when i try this (found on google) not allowed:

Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: Drive letters only mean something in Windows not in in Ubuntu. How is the second drive formatted NTFS or something else?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? In Windows did you turn off fast boot?

Comment: In Disks, click the little triangle, if it turns to a square your "D", (sdb), partition is mounted

Comment: @David: Idk how its gone NTFS i have 1 SSD and 1 hard disk. Ubuntu 22 im using i just installed it. Fast boot enabled i remember but his has second option i did not clearly remember. But i can look at it if needed. And Cameron: when i select D part in disks, its square allready

Comment: Better to label partition so then it says music or photos or whatever it is. Much better than being stuck with d:. You can use gparted, disks (gnome disks) or command line. https://askubuntu.com/questions/147319/how-can-i-give-other-drives-and-partitions-short-meaningful-names-in-nautilus  You can see labels: `lsblk -f` And then when mounted they will use that label. Better still if internal drive to create mount point & add to fstab to always mounted when you reboot.
`

Answer (score 0):

The "disk D" letter you see in Windows isn't a consistent naming. For example, if your "disk D" has another Windows installation and then you boot it, you'll see that your `D` became `C`, and the former `C` turned into `D`. If you unplug `D` and plug in a new one, it will become the new `D`. Etc.

Another thing to note: "disk D" is actually a partition, not a disk.

Linux has similar concept: there are disks `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc; and then they have partitions `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3`, etc. Similarly to those in Windows, their names may change, depending on circumstances.

So you need to figure out which disk currently refers to the HDD you wanted *(spoiler: if you only have two devices, and your "disk C" has a Linux installation as well, then most likely the "disk D" would be `sdb`, and its partitions are `sdb1`, `sdb2`, etc)*.

You may do that by looking for your disk implicit or explicit properties. Such as: the disk size — if you only have one disk of certain size, then you know which one you wanted to use. Or by partitions layout. Or by data in those partitions.

Or just execute `lsscsi`, which will show you the model names of the disks, so you can figure out which one you want. For example:

```haskell
 λ lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Netac SSD 1TB    XKR   /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  PLDS     DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH 6D11  /dev/sr0
```

Comment: I know his name for `sdb4` but in the output of `lsscsi` it calls `sdb`

Comment: @OvenKravecki right, the `sdb` is a disk name, and then `sdb1`, `sdb2`, `sdb3`, `sdb4` are all partitions. I omitted that part in my answer because I presumed that identifying the disk is enough for you, but to eliminate your confusion let me clarify: in WIndows the "disk D" is really not a disk but a partition. So yeah, you want a `sdbX` with `X` being a number, if you want, for example, to retrieve data that is on that "disk D", or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: @OvenKravecki I added a clarification to my post, hopefully now it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help. Console was saying reverse but when i go to disks and when i select the HDD part, in the desription below `NTFS — Mounted at /media/username/2224252824250081` clicked that one and realize its already mounted and i can use it as well.